# Cost of string copy constructor vs constructing string from string_view

Tags: c++, c++17

in our code base we have lots "enum-to-string" arrays, e.g. array<pair, string>> used to get a string from an enum.

Those arrays cannot be constexpr, so I was thinking of changing from string to string_view. But that will cause all places that uses strings of this to now convert from string_view to string, and I am worried about the run-time cost.

Below is example code (not real code, so don't worry about names etc.): https://godbolt.org/z/6nEh8s

```
#include <map>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

enum class Color
{
   red, blue, green
};


// Old way
using cp1 = std::pair<Color, std::string>;
const std::array colorStrings1 = {cp1{Color::red, "Red"}, cp1{Color::blue, "Blue"}, cp1{Color::green, "Green"}};

// New way
using cp2 = std::pair<Color, std::string_view>;
constexpr std::array colorStrings2 = {cp2{Color::red, "Red"}, cp2{Color::blue, "Blue"}, cp2{Color::green, "Green"}};


std::string toString1(Color color)
{
    for (const auto& [e, s] : colorStrings1) {
        if (e == color) {
            return s;
        }
    }
    return {};
}

constexpr std::string_view toString2(Color color)
{
    for (const auto& [e, s] : colorStrings2) {
        if (e == color) {
            return s;
        }
    }
    return {};
}

int main()
{
    const std::string s1{toString1(Color::red)};
    const std::string s2{toString2(Color::blue)};

    std::cout << s1 << " " << s2 << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

colorStrings2 is created at compile time - which is very good - unlike colorStrings1 which is created during startup. But I am worried that the cost of creating s2 is much larger than cost of creating s1.

I know that C++20 will eventually get constexpr strings, and then I will be able to change colorStrings1 from const to constexpr just like that (if I have understood it correctly), but that doesn't seem to be in the immediate future.

Could anyone advice me here? Is changing from colorStrings1 to colorStrings2 a good or a bad idea? This is partly an attempt to get deeper understanding of c++, so any insight is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know all implementations of `std::string` so I can't give a definite answer, but I can't see any reason why copy constructing would be cheaper than converting from a `std::string_view`. A `string_view` contains a pointer and the length so the `std::string` has all the information needed to allocate the memory just as efficiently as it does when using the copy constructor.

Comment: Well, by using `const auto s3{toString(Color::red)};`, you avoid the problem at many location like in your main function. The code would use whatever the function returns.Exact effect on performance will be highly dependant on the actual implementation and exact code but in practice would probably have negligeable impact on performance. However, if you have a lot of colors (a few hundreds), then doing **a loop might not be efficient for colors that are known only at runtime** and might have more impact on actual performance than using `string` or `string_view`.

Comment: Thanks @Phil1970. I used string for s1/s2 explicitely to highlight the issue. Using auto like you suggest, is of course a good idea and is used wherever possible. We have maybe 100 different arrays of this type, but most of them are of size 10 or less, so I don't think looping through them is much of a runtime problem.

Comment: "*then I will be able to change colorStrings1 from const to constexpr just like that*" You will not. C++20 `constexpr` allocations must *remain* in constexpr code. They're not allowed to "leak out" into non-constexpr code. So a constant expression can do allocation as a means of performing some constexpr task, but the *result* may not have allocations.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that @NicolBolas. I haven't really looked into constexpr strings yet, just assumed it would be similar to an ordinary const string, but with all data compiled in, instead of in he heap. There is no reason to wait for it then. :-(